# How to set up basic grey lined background in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the pinstripe background to show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062453/how-can-i-get-the-pinstripe-background-to-show)

I like the background in default iOS apps - the grey background with vertical lines. But I can't find it in any of the background settings for views. 
Is it just an image? Or is there any way to access it to use in my apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:

```
+ (UIColor *)groupTableViewBackgroundColor
```

Further info here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

(see **System Colors**)

Example usage:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

Edit:

Okay, seems Apple have deprecated the use of the above call, as per the UIInterface.h file:

> // Group style table view backgrounds can no longer be represented by
>   a simple color.
>
> // If you want to have a background in your own view that looks like the table view background,
>
> // then you should create an empty table view and place it behind your content.

```
+ (UIColor *)groupTableViewBackgroundColor; // This method will be deprecated during the 6.0 seed program
```

Looks like you'll have to do as Apple have suggested in their comments above.

Comment: It understands the color when I alt click it, but when I try to use it, it says "Use of undeclared Identifier". What do I do? My syntax is like this: self.view.backgroundColor = (UIColor *)groupTableViewBackgroundColor;

Comment: You don't need to cast it to a UIColor. I will edit my answer with a sample.

Comment: It is black actually. And this sucks because I have a uitableview from which i go into this screen and that one has that perfect background without single line of code and no xib.

Comment: It does that because that is the standard behaviour of a UITableView. What is the error you are getting, or what are you expecting to see exactly? Can you maybe show some code or a screenshot?

Comment: http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT2480/HT2480_01---002-en.png   Here you can see the background I want. I have a UITableView that has this background, and when I click on one item, it goes to separate view, that is not tableview and I have a label there. I want that view to have same background. And with solutions so far is is black or stone textured and not same as on screenshot.

Comment: Going to edit my answer again - found something out that explains this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nib (xib) files for your view creation then set your main views background color to ***Scroll View Textured Background Color.***

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Enjoy Coding :)